# Spacemacs ask for GIT in a Windows Installation

Tags: spacemacs

I installed spacemacs in a folder hierarchy as below

[image]

[image]

I run it through this bat file

```
set HOME=%~dp0/.spacemacs
Set VAR = %cd%
"%cd%\bin\runemacs.exe"  --insecure --debug-init
```

It runs quite OK (it launches and start updating) BUT the package **spacemacs-editing-visual** ask for git program

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Searching for program" #("No such file or directory" 0 25 (charset windows-1252)) "git")
  call-process("git" nil #<buffer  *temp*> t "version")
  apply(call-process "git" nil #<buffer  *temp*> t "version")
  process-file("git" nil #<buffer  *temp*> t "version")
  apply(process-file "git" nil #<buffer  *temp*> t "version")
```

I cannot add git.exe to PATH variable in windows as I do not have admnistrator rights, but I have git downloaded

I already tried to :

- add git.exe to emacs bin folder
- add this to init.el

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "C:/Users/JulienFERNANDEZ/OneDrive/Portable Softwares/Git/bin;" (getenv "PATH")))
```

But it is not working

Comment: Setup your `PATH` in `.spacemacs.env`.  The initial environment that Spacemacs sees is defined in that file.

Comment: thank you, I did not know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set user-level environment variables without admin rights.

Optionally, you can modify PATH only to be seen by Emacs by putting the following line in your .bat file.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:/.../Git/bin
```

Comment: adding "PATH = ... " in bat file works well ! Thx !